# Can I access iPod Library using hidden APIs?

Tags: ios, ipod

I have searched a lot about how to access audio/video files stored in iPod Library. I found an article which is saying that Apple doesn't allow you to access iPod Library, but there are some hidden APIs which allow you to do so. Does anyone have an idea of how to use those APIs to access iPod Library?

Comment: This would not be wise to do even if you could: the next release will most probably brake your application.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I'm aware there just aren't any API's to do that.

On a jailbroken phone you can do this, as you can run what you like.